# How to set hook for mouse clicked on particular application only

Tags: c++, windows, mouseevent, setwindowshookex

I am creating mouse hook on mouse click event with below code:

```
mousehook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookProc, NULL, 0);
```

It is able to call the MouseHookProc function on the mouse click.

But if I click on the other application or on the plain desktop screen still this MouseHookProc function gets called.
How can I restrict this hook event to my current application only?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would think that if you're only looking for mouse events within your application, you could probably just use the main message pump instead of a hook.

However, using a low-level mouse hook, this would handle working in your app and not interfere when in another app

```
MSLLHOOKSTRUCT *hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
// hMyMainAppHWND in the line below would already be defined 
// and set when your program starts and gets its handle
if(GetAncestor(WindowFromPoint(hookStruct->pt),GA_ROOTOWNER) != hMyMainAppHWND){ 
    // if the owner of the window where the mouse event occurred 
    // isn't your application's owning window, pass the event on
    return CallNextHookEx(mousehook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
} else {
    // The event occurred on your application
    // Do your stuff here
    // Don't forget to do one of the following:
    // if you want to consume the event, making it as though it never happened:
    // return TRUE; 
    // if you want the event to be processed as normal:
    // return CallNextHookEx(mousehook, nCode, wParam, lParam); 
}
```